# How to simulate an ATM terminal in a POS

Tags: simulation

Recently I started same projects to improve my programming skills, so I tried to develop a point of sale software. I started to bay the required hardware (ticket printer, Barcode Scanner….) to make my personal lab, but I’m unable to find how to implement the payment process using an ATM terminal.

Is there any possibility to simulate the payment process whiteout having the equipment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An 'ATM terminal' is often a magnetic stripe reader (MSR).

There are several different approaches for this:

- Keyboard 'wedge' or USB.  It hooks into the USB system and acts as another keyboard.  [Magtek](http://www.magtek.com) makes some (admittedly, this is a higher end brand).
- Integrated keyboard mag stripe reader are actually part of a keyboard as can be seen with [this Cherry Keyboard](http://www.cherrycorp.com/english/keyboards/Pos/8000/index.htm).
- [NFC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near_field_communication) devices.
- Dedicated card readers with displays (such as those by [VeriFone](http://www.verifone.com) and [Ingenico](http://www.ingenico.com/en/))

As some of these just act as keyboards themselves, yes, you can simulate it by typing the data in from a keyboard.  Otherwise, if you want to support things such as cherry keyboards and [VeriFone 870](http://www.verifone.com/media/904779/na_mx870_ds_ltr.pdf) you will probably need to get one.  Especially consider that these devices are often dedicated computers of their own, with their own programming languages and operating systems (in the case of the 870 I linked, its an embedded linux system).

There are libraries that try to abstract away the 'card reader' (and then you can go about making something that works with [JavaPOS](http://www.javapos.com/devint.html) or the like, but from experience, these can be very frustrating to work with as they often target the lowest common denominator of devices (and that can be *very* low).

Comment: +1 for JavaPOS! But please note its more of a "kit" for building POS systems rather than an out of the BOX pos system.

Comment: @JamesAnderson At a previous employer, I was on a team that modified a third party point of sales system.  Often we grumbled about JavaPOS as the interface to a number of our devices. It certainly isn't an out of the box system, but rather a way of interfacing with common POS devices. If one *really* wanted to go down that path, they could write a mock for some device.  That said, if it took more than a week or two to write it (quite possible), it might just be better to buy the device itself - some of them are not *that* expensive.

Comment: I'm trying to implement an ATOS [XENTA](http://www.banksys.com/index/en_US/5119413/5148774/XENTA.htm) Terminal which is the most used in my area. SO, I'll try to contact the company and see how they are going to respond to my questions.